# $elemMatch inside Jongo query doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, playframework-2.2, jongo

I'm having some trouble with the following query:

```
documents()
.find("{values: {$elemMatch: {name: #, value: #}}}", "Date", new DateTime()
.withDate(2027, 6, 2)
.withHourOfDay(18)
.withMinuteOfHour(06)
.withSecondOfMinute(40)
.toDate()).as(Document.class);
```

It throws no error but returns an empty list.

However, on the console it runs succesfully and presents me with a result.

I was digging through the source code and I found out that actually `Date` isn't being parsed to `ISODate("yyyy-MM-ddTxxxxx")`, and instead is being parsed to `{$date: "yyyy-MM-ddTxxxxx"}`.

I don't know if this is an issue or I'm plainly missing something. If someone can point me to the right direction, please do.

PS: as a reference, here is the console query:

```
db.documents.find({values: {$elemMatch: {"name": "Date", "value" : ISODate("2027-06-02T18:06:40Z")}}})
```

Comment: You are using different dates. Might that be it?

Comment: It was a typo, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Date created with JodaTime is not equal to the one created with ISODate : ISODate("2027-06-02T18:06:40Z")

Try to create iso DateTime as follow :

```
new DateTime("2013-01-19T15:28:58.851Z");
```

See github issue for more informations : https://github.com/bguerout/jongo/issues/187